# Google Pay Integration: Create order before Google Pay pop up gets triggered

Tags: reactjs, payment-gateway, payment-processing, google-pay

I'm currently implementing the Google Pay Checkout for my website and have a problem with the flow. When the button is clicked the popup shows up immediately after but I want to first create an order on backend because I need to have a validation for the order. On apple pay this is possible and I can close the apple payment-sheet if the order has a validation error.
On google I wanted to asynchronosly call backend for validation and afterwards fire the popup. That's not successful because the click event needs to fire the popup right away. Do you know a way how to make the backend call and on success fire the popup?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on onClick event of onGooglePaymentButtonClicked function.
In onGooglePaymentButtonClicked function, you can call your backend API for creating an order first and after a successful response call loadPaymentData for payment sheet. You can use promises with callback then/catch to open payment sheet.